# for each not bringing subview to front ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, extension-methods

I've added the following extension to `UIView`:

```
func bringViewsToFront(views : [UIView]) {
    views.forEach { (view) in
        self.bringSubviewToFront(view)
}
```

which I use like this:

```
imageOverlay.bringViewsToFront(views: [v1, v2, v3])
```

However this doesn't seem to work - whereas the traditional way below does:

```
imageOverlay.bringSubviewToFront(v1)
imageOverlay.bringSubviewToFront(v2)
imageOverlay.bringSubviewToFront(v3)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful description. Please [edit] your question and clearly explain what actually happens compared to what you expect to happen.

Comment: @rmaddy there's not much to add - nothing happens, the method doesn't get called, the UI does not update...I think it was pretty clear, this isn't a complicated method.

Comment: Your comment just stated that the method doesn't get called. I'd call that very important information missing in your question. Do you mean that `bringViewsToFront` isn't called? And your question doesn't state that the UI isn't updated. Again, important info missing from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I bet there is not problem with your for each. Just make sure that the views you're passing as parameter are direct subviews (not grandchildren subviews).